# EF6 Navigation Properties Same Type To Single Inverse

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, navigation-properties

Im not sure if this is possible.
Suppose I have this:

```
public class Thing{
    public int ThingId {get; set;}
    public virtual Item ItemA {get; set;}
    public virtual Item ItemB {get; set;}
}

public class Item{
    public int ItemId {get; set;}
}
```

How can I make a single navigation property on Item that brings me either to `ItemA` or `ItemB`? Or something where I can use `item.Thing!=null`? `item.Thing.ItemA` or `item.Thing.ItemB`?

I've tried a bunch of things but can't get it to work.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do. Can you rephrase?

Comment: I'm trying to set a navigation property on Item so it has a relationship to Thing, but when I try I get foreign key constraint errors for cascading deletes because I have two navigation properties on Thing that are of type Item. But I don't know how to either annotate the class or use fluent syntax to set the cascade deletes to false. I'm hoping there is a better way than I have thought of.

Comment: `Item` can't have two one-to-one associations to `Thing`, so how would you navigate to one `Thing.ItemA` if `Item` has many `Thing`s?

Comment: Yeah so what can I do to provide a navigation property on Item to get to Thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Thing` class there are two items, which implies that a single Item can be part of one or more Things. (Ex: the same item could be ItemA for Thing1 and it could be ItemB for Thing2). In this case it is not possible to have a FK column in the Item table because it has a one-to-many relationship with Thing.

The best you could do is have the `Item` class have a list of Things that it belongs to. You can also determine which Things it is ItemA for and which Things it is ItemB for.

```
class Thing
{
    public int ThingId { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("ItemAFor")]
    public Item ItemA { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("ItemBFor")]
    public Item ItemB { get; set; }
}

class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    // Things where this Item is ItemA
    public List<Thing> ItemAFor { get; set; }

    // Things where this Item is ItemB
    public List<Thing> ItemBFor { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, this is what I was afraid of. The reality is that Thing.ItemA and Thing. ItemB will be different Items and and Item will only ever belong to one Thing.ItemA or Thing.ItemB. If anyone else has further info that would be great. I have some ideas how I can do it but I woudl basically make ItemA/B convenience getters to lookup the Item from a List<Item> that is ordered. That way the relationship between the two is a simple one to many. Thanks!